# MIDI player/synthesizer library for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, midi, synthesizer

Does anyone know if there is a free/cheap MIDI player/synthesizer library that I can incorporate into my iPhone application?

As I understand it the iPhone doesn't have native support for MIDI playback.

To work around this limitation I've created a bank of .caf sound samples that I playback myself but I'd really like to improve the implementation and use MIDI if possible.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since 10 october of 2011, that is since iOS5, Apple has started delivering basic API for midi files playback. The API is called MusicPlayer along with MusicSequence Check this out :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009301-CH1-SW1

By setting up an appropriate Audio Unit Processing Graph you can output the sound you like.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [TiMidity++](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/#info); it looks like something that should be portable to the iPhone platform.

> *TiMidity++ is a software synthesizer. It can play MIDI files by converting
>   them into PCM waveform data; give it a
>   MIDI data along with digital
>   instrument data files, then it
>   synthesizes them in real-time, and
>   plays. It can not only play sounds,
>   but also can save the generated
>   waveforms into hard disks as various
>   audio file formats. TiMidity++ is a
>   free software, distributed under the
>   terms of GNU general public license.*
>
> *Many people have ported TiMidity++ into various platforms; FreeBSD,
>   NetBSD, many Linux distributions,
>   Windows (and/or Cygwin environment),
>   and Mac OS are known to have their own
>   versions.*

Comment: TiMidty++ is GPL I think , which would lead to you to release the source of your application for free. Also the people who built this project obtain a binary library which is only usable in Jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

This is a library I've used for MIDI synthesis in Android:
https://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Although it can't be used for iOS, I think you(and anyone who's interested) can still take a look at the implementation of the MIDI file format(i.e. how bytes are written to a .mid file) and possibly implement a MIDI library yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial library available from Crimson Technology

[Crimson Technology Library](http://www.crimsontech.jp/eng/press/softsynth_iphone.html)

I have never used it so I can't vouch for it's quality.