# is it possible to open and play midi file in iphone and change its tempo?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible to play .mid files directly via some API, or one have to convert the midi file to e.g. WAV first?  if any one know please tell me i see others all the similar question but its nt wrkng well so if any one know than please tell. thanx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play midi file on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237574/play-midi-file-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @DarkDust yes i see this que. but its not giving perfect answer ..

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use MusicPlayer APIs for playback.
2. To alter the tempo, see `MusicPlayerSetPlayRateScalar`.

Comment: have u any idea about ant API regarding this? beacause i dnt knw any thing abt MusicPlayer APIs.!

Comment: @KartikArora They came from OS X. Start there if you find no iOS samples.

Comment: is this possible to change midi file to another format with nsdata or with any other ??

Comment: i'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, perhaps `MusicSequenceFileCreateData`?

Comment: i m looking for download midi file from the server and play its in our iphone but its not support directly so i m thinking to convert it. and play it..